# Checking if the latest version are installed in the system

Tags: 11.10, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and now and then compiz crashes. So apport reported the bug to launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/872223). It tells me that I have some outdated packages installed.

```
outdated debug symbol package for libtiff4: package version 3.9.5-1ubuntu1 dbgsym 
version 3.9.4-5ubuntu6
outdated debug symbol package for libthai0: package version 0.1.15-2 dbgsym version 0.1.14-2ubuntu1
outdated debug symbol package for libdatrie1: package version 0.2.4-3 dbgsym version 0.2.4-1
outdated debug symbol package for libltdl7: package version 2.4-2ubuntu1 dbgsym version 2.2.6b-2ubuntu3
outdated debug symbol package for libstartup-notification0: package version 0.12-1 dbgsym version 0.10-1build1
```

Now considering I am running the latest version of ubuntu, I do not understand why I would have outdated packages. I checked the software sources where it is selected to receive all updates as can be seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that these are all Debug symbol packages that will help apport to report a meaningful call stack (names of the called procedures of some libraries) when the crash occured. These aren't refreshed by default. If you are eager testing a development version, you should have these installed.

The wiki describes how to install the debug packages:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

In your case however, the mentioned are very unlikely candidates to crash compiz and you may try to ignore them. If the bug squad insists on these, install the debug symbols (refer to the wiki) and recreate the bug report.